# react-native : TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state')

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm the newbie of the react-native and study with the complete code. But I can't understand the diffrence between "const" before export and after render. for example:

```
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    newToDo: ""
  };
  render() {
    const { newToDo } = this.state;
```

why I ask this is because my first init is not "export default class App extends React.Component {" but "export default function App() {". So I can't assign const or assign it and it cause the Error showing the message

> TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state')

this is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";
import ToDo from "./ToDo";

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");
export default function App() {
  const state = {
    newToDo: ""
  };
  const { newToDO } = this.state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Good or Bad</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Check Daily your habit</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>To Do List</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder={"New to do"}
          value={newToDO}
          onChangeText={this._controllNewToDo}
          returnKeyType={"done"}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <ScrollView>
          <ToDo />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  _controllNewToDo = text => {
    this.setState({
      newToDO: text
    });
  };
}
```

Comment: What  is your react-native version

Comment: If your react-native version does support hooks then you have to use useState hook to update the state

Comment: "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~36.0.0",
    "react": "~16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "~16.9.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "~8.0.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0"

Answer (score 0):

In functional component you have use useState hook to manage state.Try this,

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";
import ToDo from "./ToDo";

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");
export default function App() {
  const [newToDo, setNewToDo] = useState("");
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Good or Bad</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Check Daily your habit</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>To Do List</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder={"New to do"}
          value={newToDo}
          onChangeText={_controllNewToDo}
          returnKeyType={"done"}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <ScrollView>
          <ToDo />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

 const _controllNewToDo = text => {
    setNewToDo(text);
  };
}
```

Comment: it just changes the error message : TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state = {newToDo:"'}'). what's the big difference?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `this.setState({})` inside a functional components. So you should use a normal class component to be able to call `this.setState` or use Hooks to update state inside functionals components.

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  ScrollView
} from "react-native";
import ToDo from "./ToDo";

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get("window");

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    newToDo: ""
  };

 _controllNewToDo = text => {
    this.setState({
      newToDO: text
    });
  };

render(){
  const { newToDO } = this.state;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Good or Bad</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subTitle}>Check Daily your habit</Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.content}>
        <Text style={styles.contentTitle}>To Do List</Text>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder={"New to do"}
          value={newToDO}
          onChangeText={this._controllNewToDo}
          returnKeyType={"done"}
          autoCorrect={false}
        />
        <ScrollView>
          <ToDo />
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
 }
}

export default App;
```

Try this code!

Answer (score 0):

As  i mentioned below, If you need to use **state** and **setState({})** you should use inside class components. otherwise you should use **Hooks**, [check this](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) .I think this will help you to understand.

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Dimensions,
  TextInput,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    newToDo: 'wwe',
  };

  _controllNewToDo = text => {
    this.setState({
      newToDO: text,
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { newToDO } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <View>
          <Text>Good or Bad</Text>
          <Text>Check Daily your habit</Text>
        </View>

        <View>
          <Text>To Do List</Text>
          <TextInput
            style={{ height: 60 }}
            placeholder={'New to do'}
            value={newToDO}
            onChangeText={this._controllNewToDo}
            returnKeyType={'done'}
            autoCorrect={false}
          />
          <ScrollView
            style={{ justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Text>{newToDO}</Text>
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Feel free for doubts